# call by value-result in Pascal

Tags: parameters, pascal

How can i simulate calling by value-result in this example. Without adding variables and without change a variable name.?

```
Program one;
    var
      x:integer;
    Function two():integer;
        begin
           x:=x+1;
           two:=x;
        end;
    Procedure three(x:integer);
       begin
          x:=x+5;
          x:=two();
       end;
begin
x:=8;
three(x);
write(x);
end.
```

Comment: This will not compile. What is "dos"? What do you want to achieve? Can you come up with a simpler example?

Answer (score 0):

If it's homework, I don't think you will have to try *var* y hard to find the answer.

EDIT: The comment below is correct - maybe I was leading you up the wrong path - it's probably best to return to where we were and start from there.

Comment: Well, var ParamName: ParamType will pass ParamName *by reference*, and not *by value*, as normal, if ParamType is a simple type. But I really do not understand what the OP wants to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Do to two() what three() already does.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make out something of the question in its present form.

However, the question seems to make some sense if we suppose that the OP *is* asking how to emulate calling *by reference* (not by value) in the example code.

So... The actual code passes the parameter to `three()` by value. `three()` seems to be trying to store the value to the global variable, before calling `two()` which, in its turn, changes the global.

But the global variable is actually being used to pass the value, and so the trick is that after passing the global *by value* to `three()` the global will end up changed, as if it were passed by reference.

Only there's a little question (which seems to constitute the whole problem): how to address the global from within `three()` since the parameter's name is the same as the global's?

I don't know what version of Pascal is supposed to run this code, but if the compiler is compatible with TP/Delphi family and if the var names must be left unchanged, then I would try the only way I am aware of so far: `one.x`. Specifically, this line in `three()`'s implementation

```
x:=x+5;
```

I would change to

```
one.x:=x+5;
```

So, the global here receives the parameter value increased by 5 and calls `two()`, and `two()` changes the global once again.